# Average color of an element that has a backdrop filter? html, css, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I get the average color produced after applying a css backdrop filter?

I mean the average color behind my element. My element is a fixed navigationbar. The content behind changes so do the colors. I want the average color on scroll.

I am very familiar with css and html, but this goes beyond my knowledge.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share all relevant code and please include what you have tried.

Comment: what you mean by average color?

Comment: I want to get the average color of the content behind the area of my transparent navigation bar.

Comment: so you mean you want to get color produced after applying backdrop filter?

Comment: Yes exactly! This is what I want to achieve